# How to ignore unused imports in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

We are building a library, and part of that is a module that provides different database interfaces on different systems.

```
class DbInterface1(object):
    """Uses MySQLdb, and is useful on system A."""
    def __init__():
        pass

class DbInterface2(object):
    """Uses SQLAlchemy, and is useful on system B."""
    def __init__():
        pass
```

We'd like to skip imports that aren't used. For instance, on a system that has `MySQLdb`, we will use `DbInterface1` and should not require `SQLAlchemy` to be installed. That is, on system A, we would use it like this:

```
from ourlibrary.dbinterfaces import DbInterface1

...
```

Obviously, this will not work:

```
import MySQLdb
import sqlalchemy

class DbInterface1(object):
    """Uses MySQLdb, and is useful on system A."""
    def __init__():
        pass

class DbInterface2(object):
    """Uses SQLAlchemy, and is useful on system B."""
    def __init__():
        pass
```

We assumed that moving the imports into the classes that use them would work, since the library client won't import something it's not using, but it still has failed dependencies.

```
class DbInterface1(object):
    """Uses MySQLdb, and is useful on system A."""
    import MySQLdb

    def __init__():
        pass

class DbInterface2(object):
    """Uses SQLAlchemy, and is useful on system B."""
    import sqlalchemy

    def __init__():
        pass
```

What is the correct way to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Try moving the `import` into the `__init__()` so that the import is not done until an instance of the class is created.  If that is not sufficient, then here are more tools: https://docs.python.org/3/library/modules.html

Comment: @gammazero This works if we add the imports for every function that uses them (ideally we could make that only `__init__()`, but it is not right now). We were able to use `importlib.util.find_spec()` to check for the module's existence before import, but that will give an unexpected result if a module is missing from a system on which it should be installed (that is, if system A is missing `MySQLdb`, for some reason). So you gave us two working options :-D, but neither is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap your imports in a try-except block?

```
try:
    import MySQLdb
except ImportError:
    pass
try:
    import sqlalchemy
except ImportError:
    pass
```

This should allow to run your script even if neither module is installed.

You can modify the above method to track if the imported modules exist in order to verify if a class can be used on a certain system.

```
try:
    import MySQLdb
except ImportError:
    module_MySQLdb = False
else:
    module_MySQLdb = True
```

Then you could store that information in a class variable and check it before instantiating the class.

```
class DbInterface1(object):
    """Uses MySQLdb, and is useful on system A."""
    is_avaliable = module_MySQLdb
    def __init__(self):
        pass

if DbInterface1.is_avaliable:
    dbm = DbInterface1()
```

Or you could use a dictionary (eg `avaliable_modules = {'MySQLdb':module_MySQLdb}`) and import it along with your class.

```
from ourlibrary.dbinterfaces import DbInterface1, avaliable_modules

if avaliable_modules['MySQLdb']:
    dbm = DbInterface1()
```

Comment: As using `find_spec()`, that hides the errors if the module is not installed on a system where it is expected and is therefore less than ideal.

Comment: Yes, but you could use a variable to store the information (a bit 'hacky', i know). I updated my post to give an example.